# Regular Expressions find all values inside asterisk

Tags: java, regex, qregularexpression

i need to find all values that resides between two asterisk symbol `*data1* *data2* *data3* *data4* *data5*`how do i set Regular Expression in java for this particular string. 
i tried indexof ..but it ain't  work

Answer (score 0):

this works fine...

```
String pattern = "\*([^*^\s*$]+)\*";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher mat = pt.matcher(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

To find only the values (without the asterisks). (Not find values completely blank):

```
(?<=\*)(\s*[^*\s]+\s*)
```

Comment: Why 'This answer is not useful'? It's the only that finds 'values'.